# SQLITE "Database is locked" (Java - Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

When I try to update (or replace) records in my database it shows "Database is locked" error!

For example, this button should update the user's account details:

```
 JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
 btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      Connection connection3 = SqliteConnection.dbConnector();
      PreparedStatement pst1 = null;

    try {

        String q1 = "replace into Users (FullName,UserName,Email,Password,Question,Answer,UserType) values('"+FullName.getText()+"' ,'"+MainPage.getAuthUser()+"' , '"+Email.getText()+"', '"+Pass.getPassword().toString()+"' , '"+Question.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' , '"+Answer.getText()+"' , '"+UserType.getSelectedItem().toString()+"') ";
      //String q1 = "update Users FullName = '"+FullName.getText()+"' where UserName like '"+MainPage.getAuthUser()+"'  ";
        pst1 = connection3.prepareStatement(q1);

        pst1.executeUpdate();
        pst1.close();
        connection3.close();

    } catch (SQLException e6) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e6);
    }
   }
});
```

I've used the same connection for inserting records (create account) and for selecting some of them (login) and those buttons work fine.

I even have tried closing both, connection and statement, in a finally block, but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database gets locked by any active transaction.

The problem is not with thie code (although `try`/`finally` would be a good idea), but probably with some other code in the same application. You have to check all other database accesses.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check what *locks* the database file.
under Linux you can use following command to check the process locking DB file:

> $ fuser db_name.db